# Markdown viewer for file list

Tags: command-line, software-rec, markdown

I'm looking for a command line **Markdown viewer for many .md files** somehow similar to image viewers.

I need:

- simple/fast navigation: preferably left, right arrows (no combinations like :n, :p),
- and a list of .md files as an argument or taken from current dir,
- clean output is a plus.

It may be also achieved by some sophisticated pipe sequence or any customized parameters/shell variables. Anything that works.

Comment: would mdless (https://github.com/ttscoff/mdless) fit for purpose ?

Comment: @MC68020 I already have mdcat, mdless and other tools, but cannot find a way to use it with multiple input files.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for an app that will load *multiple* \*.md files into a pager-*like* output?

Comment: @Seamus yes, "pager-like" - I think so. I know that .md and other text files can be quite long and they often need vertical and horizontal scroll, but still… what I'd like to achieve is to have a bunch of small text files (or preferably .md) that would be kind of "frames" or steps that I could view and switch easily and fast.

Comment: @sZpak so, something like a slideshow, where each slide is defined in markdown?

Comment: @sZpak something like [this](https://textual.textualize.io/widget_gallery/#markdownviewer), for multiple files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed something similar a while ago, so today I sat down and cleaned up the code to make it somewhat useful. It's licensed under GPLv3:

https://github.com/marcusmueller/markmedown

If you have access to textual >= 0.11.0 (as of 2023-11-17, that's practically only the case on Fedora 39), you can directly run `markmedown` from that repository.

Otherwise, you'd want to install a newer textual in a virtualenv and then use that. To ease that for local installations, the repo contains a `markmedown.sh` setup and launcher script. Run it *once* from the repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/marcusmueller/markmedown
cd markmedown
./markmedown.sh
```

And then just copy `markmedown.sh` somewhere in your `$PATH`.

Usage is very simple:

```bash
markmedown.sh FILE1.md FILE2.md …
```

<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> keys to switch between files, <kbd>q</kbd> to quit.

If you want to show an outline of each file on the side, add `-t` as option.

[image: Animated demo]

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but looks good.